# An error with \begin{tabular}{@{}l*{2}{>{\textbackslash\ttfamily}l}l<{Example text}@{}}

Tags: tables, booktabs

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\normal}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{2}{>{\textbackslash\ttfamily}l}l<{Example text}@{}}
  \toprule[1.5pt]
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\head{Input}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\head{Output}}\\
  & \normal{\head{Command}} & \normal{\head{Declaration}} & \normal{} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(l){4-4}
  Family & textrm & rmfamily & \rmfamily\\
  & textsf & sffamily & \sffamily\\
  & texttt & ttfamily & \ttfamily\\
  \bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The above snippet generates an error regarding

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{2}{>{\textbackslash\ttfamily}l}l<{Example text}@{}}
```

And, I don't understand the error. It says "ERROR: LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg." What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The insertion of content at the start or end of a column entry is performed by `>{<start>}` or `<{<end>}`. This functionality is supplied by the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array), which you've not included:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\normal}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{2}{>{\textbackslash\ttfamily}l}l<{Example text}@{}}
  \toprule[1.5pt]
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\head{Input}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\head{Output}}\\
  & \normal{\head{Command}} & \normal{\head{Declaration}} & \normal{} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(l){4-4}
  Family & textrm & rmfamily & \rmfamily\\
  & textsf & sffamily & \sffamily\\
  & texttt & ttfamily & \ttfamily\\
  \bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, right.... How can I prevent this mistake from happening again?

Comment: @crocket: Get a tattoo that reads "Remember to include `\usepackage{array}`"?

Comment: You mean there is no solution in LaTeX.

Comment: @crocket: It is functionality added *in addition to* the default, so it is supplied as "an extension" through a package. Some packages include `array` by default, like `\usepackage{tabularx}`... Some document classes also add this functionality. As of new, there's not much more one can do than remembering it...